# SQL - Columns will not sum

Tags: sql

New to coding SQL and have just been Googling my way to write Queries that work for me but I am having a hard time with the one I am currently working on.

The goal of the query is to sum the AHT and ACW columns based on the week number. I got it to sum but it is still showing 2 rows for Week 1.

I am not sure where to look. Can you help me please?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT([AgentAcdId],7) As EmployeeNumber,    
    (SUM(TotalPeriodHandleSeconds)*1./SUM(handledcontacts))/86400 AS AHT,
    (SUM(TotalPeriodWorkSeconds)*1./SUM(handledcontacts))/86400  AS ACW,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('601','603','605') Then 'Billing'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('606','608','653','668','683','684','685') Then 'Delivery'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('344','345','346','347','348','349','352','405','407','611','612','614','616','619','650','652','654','655','656','674','675','677','678','680','682','689','690','691','700','734','735','758') Then 'Other'
        END AS Type,

    DATEPART(wk, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) As Week,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 1 Then 'January'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 2 Then 'February'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 3 Then 'March'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 4 Then 'April'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 5 Then 'May'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 6 Then 'June'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 7 Then 'July'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 8 Then 'August'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 9 Then 'September'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 10 Then 'October'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 11 Then 'November'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 12 Then 'December'
        END AS Month,
    DATEPART(yy, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) As Year,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('1', '2','3') Then '1'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('4', '5','6') Then '2'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('7', '8','9') Then '3'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('10', '11','12') Then '4'
        END AS Quarter

      FROM [CWFM].[wfm].[AgentProductivityStatisticsInterval] APSI


  Group by  AgentAcdId, DATEPART(wk, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart),  RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3), DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart), DATEPART(yy, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart)
  Having sum(HandledContacts) <> 0
```

A sample of the output is below

```
EmployeeNumber  AHT ACW Type    Week    Month   Year    Quarter
3405500 0.003987269 0.001315438 NULL    1   January 2020    1
3405500 0.004678819 0.003130787 NULL    1   January 2020    1
```

Thank you!

Comment: @KenWhite - Uh,... no, it's not.  The behavior of GROUP BY is consistent across every major DBMS, and while having the input data would let us be more specific, there's plenty here to write an answer that addresses the problem.  I'm all for asking people to write complete questions that give enough information, but that shouldn't be in lieu of making an effort to understand the question as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive it has to do with the fact that the two lines are not part of the same Q: ServiceQueueAcdId and they are not isted

Run the query below:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT([AgentAcdId],7) As EmployeeNumber,    
    (SUM(TotalPeriodHandleSeconds)*1./SUM(handledcontacts))/86400 AS AHT,
    (SUM(TotalPeriodWorkSeconds)*1./SUM(handledcontacts))/86400  AS ACW,
    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('601','603','605') Then 'Billing'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('606','608','653','668','683','684','685') Then 'Delivery'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('344','345','346','347','348','349','352','405','407','611','612','614','616','619','650','652','654','655','656','674','675','677','678','680','682','689','690','691','700','734','735','758') Then 'Other'
ELSE  Then 'NoListed'
        END AS Type,

    DATEPART(wk, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) As Week,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 1 Then 'January'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 2 Then 'February'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 3 Then 'March'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 4 Then 'April'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 5 Then 'May'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 6 Then 'June'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 7 Then 'July'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 8 Then 'August'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 9 Then 'September'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 10 Then 'October'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 11 Then 'November'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) = 12 Then 'December'
        END AS Month,
    DATEPART(yy, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) As Year,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('1', '2','3') Then '1'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('4', '5','6') Then '2'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('7', '8','9') Then '3'
        WHEN DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart) in ('10', '11','12') Then '4'
        END AS Quarter

      FROM [CWFM].[wfm].[AgentProductivityStatisticsInterval] APSI


  Group by  AgentAcdId, DATEPART(wk, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart),  DATEPART(mm, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart), DATEPART(yy, AgentProductivityStatisticsIntervalStart),

    CASE
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('601','603','605') Then 'Billing'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('606','608','653','668','683','684','685') Then 'Delivery'
        WHEN RIGHT(ServiceQueueAcdId,3) IN ('344','345','346','347','348','349','352','405','407','611','612','614','616','619','650','652','654','655','656','674','675','677','678','680','682','689','690','691','700','734','735','758') Then 'Other'
ELSE  Then 'NoListed'
        END

  Having sum(HandledContacts) <> 0
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! So even though I had ServiceQueueAcdId in the Group by section, it wasn't in the right format?

Comment: The problem was that you were grouping by ServiceQueueAcdId. Some service queue in you ACD are not present in Billing, Delivery or Other. When you do that, it will create a row for each queue that received a call. Plus the two queues that showed up in the result were not aggregated. So I aggregated them in the NOt Listed group as you see in my code.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

You're not `SELECT`ing everything you `GROUP BY`, so it's not clear from the output why multiple rows are returned.  (For example, you `SELECT` only part of the AgentAcdId value but you `GROUP BY` the whole thing.)

Try writing the query so that each `GROUP BY` expression is also in the `SELECT` and you should be able to see what's going on.  That may not be the output you want, but once you know what's wrong and have updated the rest of your query accordingly, you can change it back.

Comment: Based on what you said here, which is not a complete answer, couldn't you also assume that the code shown is not even what the OP actually pasted into the question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try this in future when I am troubleshooting.